# Where to mount an additional drive?

Tags: mount

I just have installed a new HDD to store my collection of photographs. The question is where to mount it.

I have considered mounting it to `~/Pictures`, but it is already in use and I do not want to mix my photograph collection with some random images on my computer. I also thought of `~/photographs` or `/home/photographs` or `/photographs` , I am just not sure which way is correct/the cleanest possible.

I know how to edit `/etc/fstab` and am therefore not asking how, but just where to mount new drives.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the system mounts removable media in `/media`. For user mounted devices, the standard is to use `/mnt`.

Make a new directory:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/my_mountpoint
```

Mount the new drive there:

```
$ mount /dev/<your device> /mnt/my_mountpoint
```

Comment: You might want to mention `/media` and udisks. At least on Linux with most desktop environments.

Comment: Yes. Usually `/media` is where the system mounts removable media. `/mnt` is where the user can mount whatever we wants.

Comment: Right. I suggest you [edit] your answer to mention it. Consider that it's possible that the OP (or a future reader) has seen the removable drive behavior. Or that a future reader might be dealing with a removable drive.